# Which Spring Framework provides REST Services?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, rest, spring-mvc

In `Spring` we have `Spring WS` for SOAP API's.

**My Concern :**

- I want to implement REST services with Spring
- Want to follow proven best practices
- Want to deliver it in time ( Avoid redo )

Is there any `Spring Framework` for `REST Services` like ( `Spring WS` is for **SOAP API** ) ?

I was unable to find a `one answer` blueprint for `RESTful services` and `best practices`.

( Feel free to leave **comments** )

**Update :**

- If we don't need any `framework` then how do you make sure you follow `Best Practices`
- I mean, developer might unknowingly miss some or might overdo some.
- So, why don't we have any for REST and then where should one refer to for the void ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a Framework to implement REST Services with Spring, it's just a possibile way to how you can implement Services in Spring.

As the official doc [Spring - Creating RESTful services](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch18s02.html) says:

> Spring's annotation-based MVC framework serves as the basis for
>   creating RESTful Web Services.

So, if you haven't added `spring-web` & `spring-webmvc` dependencies to your project, this can be something you have to do.